"Why doesn't webGL preserve previous drawings?
I have a small drawing application where each time the mouse moves, the new coordinates are fed into a buffer in WebGL. I assumed that when I call gl.drawArrays, I only need to draw the new points, not the old ones, because they were rendered previously. However, the old points disappear even though I haven't called gl.clear. Why is this happening?
// every time feed new points
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer)
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, index, new Float32Array(points))


// only draw new Points
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, lastDrawnPoints, newPoints.length / 2)


"Why is this happening?" - that would probably be a lot easier to determine with a proper [mre] of the issue, rather than just a handful of lines that lack context.

Because your asumption is wrong, that is not how it works.
A 3D scene is not a chalkboard.
You have to render your entire scene at every frame.
simple 3D animation in webgl example

I assumed that each draw call writes to the drawing buffer, and if I don't clear it, the previous state remains unchanged. Is this assumption incorrect?

It's not really a drawing buffer like the one we use when doing 2D graphics. It is geometric information that will be fed to the rendering pipeline. The rendering is fast so it's not really a problem. The slow part is loading arrays of data, those can stay in memory from a a frame to another but you still have to order webgl to draw them at your desired position and transformation and according to a viewpoint.
